# Property 'splitViewBarButtonItem' not found on object of type 'id<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm following `Stanford cs193p lesson 7` about using `SplitViewControllers` and protocols.
I'm doing the same exact stuff the professor is doing (checked multiple times) but I get this error over and over.

I defined a protocol in `SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIBarButtonItem *splitViewBarButtonItem;
@end
```

in my master CalculatorViewController.h

```
@interface CalculatorViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```

in CalculatorViewController.m

```
-(id <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>)splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter
{
    id detailVC = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    if(![detailVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter)]){
        detailVC = nil;
    }
    return detailVC;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{ 
    [super awakeFromNib];
    super.splitViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

and later when I try to set the barButtonItem

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
    willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
         withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
      forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = self.title;
    [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter].splitViewBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}
```

I keep getting the error in the title as if I didn't properly declare the protocol and the delegate. I really don't know where else to look for errors since I'm following what the Stanford's professor does line by line, letter by letter.
The error is in this line, specifically:

```
[self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter].splitViewBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

Comment: more details on the error please

Comment: error shows up when I try to use the dot notation to set splitViewBarButtonItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have an infinite recursion in your code:

```
-(id <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>)splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter
{
    id detailVC = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    if(![detailVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter)]){
        detailVC = nil;
    }
    return [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter] ? UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIInterfaceOrientation) : NO;
}
```

The method calls itself in the return statement and there's no abort condition. 
Second, even if that method would return a value, it would return a `BOOL` but it's supposed to return an `id<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>`.

Third, either the return type of the method is wrong or the name is misleading. You have a protocol called `SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter` and the name of the method is `splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter`. So from the name I would expect it to return an `id<SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter>` not an `id<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>`.

Last but not least, your `SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter` protocol is not implemented by the `CalculatorViewController`.

So there are a lot of problems with your code and I would suggest to check that even more often.

Comment: thank you very much! regarding the infinite recursion I think I messed it up posting it here: it was just `return detailVC;`.
What was causing the error was the return type of the `SplitViewBarButtonItem` method.
I just noticed that it didn't depend on the protocol either (a different view is set as the delegate for `SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter` later on).
I don't have any experience at all in obj-c and iOS, thanks again for the answer even if the question was kind of dumb :)